# Problemas con el código no me deja ir a la opción 1

Tags: c++

Tengo problemas con mi código y siempre me vuelve a mostrar el menú, siempre y cuando no pongo el 0 que es del salir. Necesito hacer esto ya que con eso puedo seguir con mi proyecto. Ayúdenme a encontrar porque no me deja ingresar a la primera opción, para poder seguir trabajando con el archivo que se tiene que leer (si todo  se trabaja con la primera opción y solo necesito saber porque no puedo hacer que lea un archivo de texto).

Ni siquiera me permite ingresar al void leer archivo para poder ver si se puede seguir trabajando normalmente. Soy novato en esto y no tengo mucho conocimiento, así que me vendría de perlas que me echen una mano con lo que es la primera opción que se muestra en el código. Please necesito hacer  que funcione. También seguiré intentando cómo poder hacer las otras opciones, pero sin el leer archivo no podre continuar.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fstream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void leerarchivo();
    void matrizdepalabras();
    void matrizdepalabrasrepetidas();
    void palabraspalindromo();
    void listadeverbo();


int main()
{
    int opcion;
    bool repetir = true;
    char archivo;
    
    do {
        // Texto del menú que se verá cada vez
        cout << "\n\nMenu de Opciones" << endl;
        cout << "1.-Leer y cargar el archivo"<<endl;
        cout << "2.-Mostrar mastriz de palabras repetidas"<<endl;
        cout << "3.-Mostrar matriz de palabras repetidas en orden"<<endl;
        cout << "4.-Mostrar lista de palabras PALINDROMO"<<endl;
        cout << "5.-lista de palabras que son verbos"<<endl;
        cout << "0. SALIR" << endl;
        cout << "Elija una opcion en orden gerarquico porfavor:";
    
        cin >> opcion;
        
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 1                
                void leerarchivo();
               
                break;
                
            case 2:
                // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 2                
                void matrizdepalabras();
                
                break;
                
            case 3:
                // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 3                
                void matrizdepalabrasrepetidas();
                    
                break;
                
            case 4:
                // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
                void palabraspalindromo();
                            
                break;
                
            case 5:
                // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 4                
                void listadeverbo();
                     
                break;
                
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break;
        }        
    } while (repetir);
     
    return 0;
}

void leerarchivo(){
    string nombreArchivo,texto;
    ifstream archivo;
    cout <<"hola que tal";   
    
    cout<<"Digite el nombre o la ubicacion del archivo o fichero: ";
    getline(cin,nombreArchivo);
    
    archivo.open(nombreArchivo.c_str(),ios::in); //Abrimos el archivo en modo lectura
    
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    
    while(!archivo.eof()){ //mientras no sea final del archivo
        getline(archivo,texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }
    
    archivo.close(); //Cerramos el archivo
} 
    
void matrizdepalabras(){
    

}
```

Comment: Junto con la solución que te ha aportado @eferion, cuando declaras las funciones, puedes además indicarle al compilador que no tienes ningún parámetro, es decir, `void leerarchivo (void)`, `void matrizdepalabras (void)`... y así en todas siempre y cuando todas esas funciones no necesiten de parámetros de entrada.

Comment: @Londo en C++ no es como en C, en C++ no hace falta poner `void` en las funciones que no reciben parámetros, el compilador lo va a tratar correctamente

Answer (score 2):

Reemplaza esto

```
        case 1:
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 1                
            void leerarchivo();
           
            break;
```

Por esto

```
        case 1:
            // Lista de instrucciones de la opción 1                
            leerarchivo(); // <<--- sobra el void
           
            break;
```

Ya has declarado la función, luego el compilador ya sabe que la función no devuelve absolutamente nada, no es necesario que se lo estés recordando a cada uso.

Y lo mismo para el resto de opciones